# CPU Time consuming

Tags: cpulimit

I'm beginner into dev and i need your help to understand what does it means "QueuableHandler" and "DB" on screen below. I need to find what consumes a lot CPU time, and i see it is QueuableHandler" en "DB" , but could not find on google information on it.
thanks a lot for your help[image]

[image]

Comment: I would recommend you replace your image with a cropped version minus the query editor section.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing here is consuming "a lot of CPU time." The entire transaction is only just over 1/4th of a second. The database time is less than 1/10th of one second. This is well within normal range for an object with a few/none triggers/validation rules/workflow rules/etc. You may be looking at the wrong log file.